# opencv video window not opening though sucess true and camera opens wbut no video window

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

Can somebody help me with finding error on the below code?

I am working on tutorial Face Detect Attendance system python
opencv but cv fails to load camera....

I tried to catch success true...it does I get no error and yet cam
window not showing.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
     success, img = cap.read()
     imgS = cv2.resize(img,(0,0),None,0.25,0.25)
     imgS = cv2.cvtColor(imgS, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
     facesCurFrame = face_recognition.face_locations(imgS)
     encodesCurFrame = face_recognition.face_encodings(imgS,facesCurFrame)
     
     for encodeFace,faceLoc in zip(encodesCurFrame,facesCurFrame):
         matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(encodeListKnown,encodeFace)
         faceDis = face_recognition.face_distance(encodeListKnown,encodeFace)
         #print(faceDis)
         matchIndex = np.argmin(faceDis)
         
         if matches[matchIndex]:
             name = classNames[matchIndex].upper()
             #print(name)
             y1,x2,y2,x1 = faceLoc
             y1, x2, y2, x1 = y1*4,x2*4,y2*4,x1*4
             cv2.rectangle(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)
             cv2.rectangle(img,(x1,y2-35),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),cv2.FILLED)
             cv2.putText(img,name,(x1+6,y2-6),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(255,255,255),2)
             markAttendance(name)
             cv2.imshow('Webcam',img)
             cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: if there is no window it means that there are no matched faces on the frame

Comment: With bleow code still not working ....        if faceDis[matchIndex]< 0.50:
            name = classNames[matchIndex].upper()
            markAttendance(name)
        else: name = 'Unknown'
        #print(name)
        y1,x2,y2,x1 = faceLoc
        y1, x2, y2, x1 = y1*4,x2*4,y2*4,x1*4
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x1,y2-35),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),cv2.FILLED)
        cv2.putText(img,name,(x1+6,y2-6),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(255,255,255),2)

Comment: After setting everything up, your code is working properly (except of `markAttendance(name)`). There is a chance that `encodeListKnown` is not correct. Your problem is not reproducible... If you want to be answered, post an image of a sample face (don't use `success, img = cap.read()`), post `encodeListKnown`. Add all the `import`s. Make sure your code sample is executable.

Comment: For testing the camera, add the lines: `cv2.imshow('Webcam', img)` and `cv2.waitKey(1)` right after `success, img = cap.read()`.

Answer (score 1):

Keep below two lines out of the for loop.

```
cv2.imshow('Webcam',img)
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Code will look like this

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
     success, img = cap.read()
     imgS = cv2.resize(img,(0,0),None,0.25,0.25)
     imgS = cv2.cvtColor(imgS, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
     facesCurFrame = face_recognition.face_locations(imgS)
     encodesCurFrame = face_recognition.face_encodings(imgS,facesCurFrame)
     
     for encodeFace,faceLoc in zip(encodesCurFrame,facesCurFrame):
         matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(encodeListKnown,encodeFace)
         faceDis = face_recognition.face_distance(encodeListKnown,encodeFace)
         #print(faceDis)
         matchIndex = np.argmin(faceDis)
         
         if matches[matchIndex]:
             name = classNames[matchIndex].upper()
             #print(name)
             y1,x2,y2,x1 = faceLoc
             y1, x2, y2, x1 = y1*4,x2*4,y2*4,x1*4
             cv2.rectangle(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)
             cv2.rectangle(img,(x1,y2-35),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),cv2.FILLED)
             cv2.putText(img,name,(x1+6,y2-6),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(255,255,255),2)
             markAttendance(name)
     cv2.imshow('Webcam',img)
     cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Reason: In your current code, opencv will not open the window unless there is a detection as it is inside the for loop.